# Replacing every number in a string with a random char

Tags: php, string, random, numbers

I want to replace every number in a string like `ABC123EFG` with another random char.
My idea was to generate a random string with the number of all numbers in `$str` and replace every digit by `$array[count_of_the_digit]`, is there any way to do this without a for-loop, for example with regex?

```
$count = preg_match_all('/[0-9]/', $str);
$randString = substr(str_shuffle(str_repeat("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", $count)), 0, $count);
$randString = str_split($randString);
$str = preg_replace('/[0-9]+/', $randString[${n}], $str); // Kinda like this (obviously doesnt work)
```

Comment: I can't think of any way you're going to get a string of random characters without a loop. Why don't you want to use a loop? (Is it just me, or does it sometimes seem like there's someone telling new programmers that loops are bad?)

Comment: Its not that loops are bad, it just seems that this can be done a lot more cleanly with regex or something similiar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `preg_replace_callback()`

```
$str = 'ABC123EFG';

echo preg_replace_callback('/\d/', function(){
  return chr(mt_rand(97, 122));
}, $str);
```

It would output something like:

```
ABCcbrEFG
```

If you want upper case values, you can change `97` and `122` to their ASCII equivalent of `64` to `90`.

Comment: Is there a way to do this in python?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [preg_replace_callback](https://php.net/preg_replace_callback) to call a function where the returned value is the replacement. Here is an example that does what you want:

```
<?php
function preg_replace_random_array($string, $pattern, $replace){
    //perform replacement
    $string = preg_replace_callback($pattern, function($m) use ($replace){
            //return a random value from $replace
            return $replace[array_rand($replace)];
        }, $string);

    return $string;
}

$string = 'test123asdf';

//I pass in a pattern so this can be used for anything, not just numbers.
$pattern = '/\d/';
//I pass in an array, not a string, so that the replacement doesn't have to
//be a single character. It could be any string/number value including words.
$replace = str_split('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ');

var_dump(preg_replace_random_array($string, $pattern, $replace));
```

Comment: `array_flip(range('A', 'Z'))`?