# Replace curly braced expression with one item from the expression

Tags: php, regex, random, preg-replace-callback

Here is a sample string:

```
{three / fifteen / one hundred} this is the first random number, and this is the second, {two / four}
```

From the brackets, I need to return a random value for example:

```
One hundred is the first random number, and this is the second, two
```

My code:

```
function RandElement($str) {
    preg_match_all('/{([^}]+)}/', $str, $matches);
    return print_r($matches[0]);
}
$str = "{three/fifteen/one hundred} this is the first random number, and this is the second, {two/four}";
RandElement($str);
```

Result:

```
(
    [0] => {three/fifteen/one hundred}
    [1] => {two/four}
)
```

And I don't quite understand what to do next. Take the first string from an array and pass it back through a regex?

Comment: Look into [`preg_replace_callback`](https://www.php.net/preg_replace_callback).

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42816112/2943403

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`preg_replace_callback`](https://www.php.net/preg_replace_callback):

```php
$str = "{three/fifteen/one hundred} this is the first random number, and this is the second, {two/four}";
echo preg_replace_callback('~\{([^{}]*)}~', function ($x) {
    return array_rand(array_flip(explode('/', $x[1])));
}, $str);
```

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/GVFnm)

Note that Group 1 captured with the `([^{}]*)` pattern (and accessed via `$x[1]`) is split with a slash using `explode('/', $x[1])` and then a random value is picked up using [`array_rand`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php). To return the value directly, the array is [`array_flip`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php)ped.